# How can I symbolize my rasters in ArcGIS to match levelplot in R?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, symbology, levelplot

I need to create more customized maps in ArcGIS than what I have in R, however I can't seem to get the outputs to match. I have model outputs as ascii that I have converted to tiffs in R and plotted:

```
ras<-function(x,b){
  m<-x
  crs(m)<-"+proj=lcc +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"

  if (require(rgdal)) {
    writeRaster(m,filename=paste0(b,".tif"),driver="GTiff",overwrite=TRUE)
  } 
}
ras(raster,"Example")
#plot
col<-rasterTheme(region=brewer.pal(8,"YlOrRd"))
levelplot(raster,par.settings=col)
```

Using those tiffs, I am trying to display the tiffs in ArcMap, however the surfaces look slightly different. Here is a screenshot to illustrate this:

[image]

On the right is the same raster in R using `levelplot` however there is a slight gradient outside the "hotspots" with values around 0.1-0.2. The same cannot be seen on the raster to the left.

Is there a way to get the symbology consistent across the two? I'm wondering if my conversion is the reason as to why these are different.

Answer (score 1):

In R you set number of colors to 8 while in ArcMap you selected a gradient. To get the same results in ArcMap try to select classified renderer and devide colors into 8 equally spaced classes

Comment: I've fooled around with this and gotten close, however it's around 17 classes in ArcMap. If you view the legend levelplot, there are 16 distinct colours despite 8 being specified. I'm hoping there's a more effective way to replicate them.